# Remove the cursor line background highlighting in vim

Tags: vim, plugins

All the characters in the line where the cursor is positioned are highlighted with pink background. It only happens when I start gvim. In order to make it disappear I change the background to dark which showhow disables the pink background. And then swap back to light background. This is getting annoying cause everytime I start I have to enter these command. Is there a way to disable it completely on startup.

THEME being used: Solarized.

Screenshot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/83343363/default.png

I also tried commenting out "set cursorline" but it still didn't work. The problem exists in molokai as well.

Comment: Probably this is not related to your problem, but pathogen#infect should really be called before setting up filetype plugins on, so that you can install file type plugins in pathogen. And you should only need to enable filetype plugins once.

Comment: [SOLVED] there was a "highlight_cursor_line.vim" in my plugins directory. Removed it and its back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow 'cursorline' is being set, even after you comment it out in your .vimrc. I presume you restarted Vim after you did that. So you must be setting it in another place as well, perhaps in a plugin or even ftplugin file. Run the following command to find out where so you can remove it there, too:

```
:verbose set cursorline?
```